# Как передать переменную из кода Delphi на скрипт fastreport?

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

Есть готовый созданный отчет c помощью Delphi и компонента Fastreport.
В скрипте fastreport:

```
procedure Memo9OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if (<frxDBDataset1."saldo_deb">+<frxDBDataset1."saldo_kr">-SUM(<frxDBDataset1."Sum_db">,MasterData1)+SUM(<frxDBDataset1."Sum_kr">,MasterData1))<0 then
  begin
    Memo9.text:='[ABS(<frxDBDataset1."saldo_deb">+<frxDBDataset1."saldo_kr">-SUM(<frxDBDataset1."Sum_db">,MasterData1)+SUM(<frxDBDataset1."Sum_kr">,MasterData1))]';
    /*1*/ Memo31.text:='Исходящий остаток (актив)';
  end else
    Memo9.text:='';
end;
```

В delphi есть условие:

```
if combobox1.itemindex=0 then name_file='russian.ini'
else name_file='english.ini';
```

Так вот, сам вопрос: Как передать переменную с value в fastreport, чтоб смог использовать в *1* ее так?:

```
if name_file='russian.ini' then Memo31.text:='Исходящий остаток (актив)'
else Memo31.text:='Outbound balance (asset)';
```

Comment: Сделать callback функцию в отчете, которая сходит в ваш код за правильным значением для `Memo31.text`?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci а вот так делать не надо - нарушается инкапсуляция. Отчету надо отдать параметры для построения, а дальше он должен сделать все сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

1. Добавьте в шаблон отчета входную переменную `lang`.
2. Из Delphi передавайте в нее значение 1 или 2, в зависимости от выбранного языка.

   ```
   fastReportObject.Variables['lang'] := 1;
   ```
3. В Шаблоне смотрите значение переменной и выбирайте правильный язык текста.

   ```
   procedure Memo31OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
   begin
     if <lang> = 1 then
       Memo31.text:='Исходящий остаток (актив)'
     else
       Memo31.text:='Outbound balance (asset)';
   end;
   ```

или даже записать условие прямо в значение поля:

```
[IIF(<lang> = 1, 'Исходящий остаток (актив)', 'Outbound balance (asset)')]
```

---

Альтернативное решение - хранить локализации в БД и получать текст для полей из БД, как и для данных.

---

Другое решение - сделать и поддерживать 2 шаблона отчетов (если форматирование текста важнее удобства изменений и "дублирования кода")

Comment: Kromster, спасибо большое, выручили)